# Called JPARepository Implementation inside a Class returns NullPointerException Error

Tags: java, spring, annotations

i am working on a Spring java project. I have this class that needs to update a db row. I am using JPARepository for db manipulations. But when I call this implementation from within a class, this returns a NullPointerException.

```
imports ...

public class TestClass {

   @Inject
   private JPARepositoryImpl jparepositoryimpl;

   public void split () {
      jparepositoryimpl.findByFilename(filename);
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you create the instance of TestClass? Do you call new TestClass()?

Comment: This TestClass is intended to split a file. Once splitting is done, I need to call the jparepository function to find a row by filename column.

Comment: Yeah, nice comment, but that doesn't answer my question. Please show the code, where you instantiate TestClass.

Comment: Sorry, i got ur question wrong. Yes, I instantiate TestClass as new TestClass().

Comment: `@WebServlet("/ServletA")
public class ServletA extendes HttpServlet {
 TestClass testclass = new TestClass();

  protected doGet(...) {
    testclass.split();
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate a class with `new TestClass()`, Spring doesn't know anything about that instance and autowiring won't work. You have to make TestClass a Spring Bean (by annotating it with `@Component` or create the object instance through a `@Bean` annotated method) and inject it where you need it.

Comment: the lines that returns the error is the jparepositoryimpl.findByFilename(filename);

Comment: seems like TestClass doesn't recorgnize my jparepositoryimpl? :(

Comment: Of course, because TestClass is not managed by Spring, JPARepositoryImpl won't be injected by Spring. I suggest you start with some basic tutorials about how the injection in Spring works.